# Magento 2: New container not showing

Tags: magento2, containers

I'm trying to add a new container to a layout (extending Magento Blank) but it's not rendering in HTML. I added the following to:

app/design/frontend/VENDOR/MYTHEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<container name="mike.container" as="mikeContainer" label="Mike Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="mike-container" />
```

I cleaned the cache and refreshed the page and then looked at the source code rendered by my browser but a div with a class of "mike-container" doesn't exist.

Do I need to do something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

David's answer is correct, but his example doesn't work (for me anyway).

If you swap the text block in his example with a template block you'll see the container then displays.

My full example to get it working:

app/design/frontend/**PACKAGE**/**THEME**/Magento_Cms/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <container name="mike.container" as="mikeContainer" label="Mike Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="mike-container">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="testing" template="Magento_Cms::test.phtml" />
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/design/frontend/**PACKAGE**/**THEME**/Magento_Cms/templates/test.phtml

```
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem suscipit, adipisci, cum quos, alias similique ad eum at deserunt eligendi enim dignissimos, unde vero ipsam voluptatibus cumque accusantium! Obcaecati, quasi.</h2>
```

**Result**

[image]

If I remove the template block, the container is no longer rendered.

Comment: hm ok :o maybe the arguments in the example are wrong, did not have a running env here to test it (y)

Comment: Guys, thank you both very much for you help!

Comment: Thx Ben Crook, this helps get close to making custom widget layout position

Answer (score 8):

magento2 seems to render a container only if the children generate a html output: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php#L571

So I think you need to have at least one childblock with an output in order to have the container rendered

you should be able to test this with a text block like this:

```
<container name="mike.container" as="mikeContainer" label="Mike Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="mike-container">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="testtextblock">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="text" xsi:type="string">TestText</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>
```

Comment: Is the Text block supposed to output the text by default? I can't get this example to work. I'm attempting to output text as a label prior to a Html/Links block.

Comment: Text block doesnt have constructor defintion so you cant pass arguments. Use action instead:  <action method="setText"><argument name="text" xsi:type="string">TestText</argument></action>